# Dice odds of rolling 6's

Tags: probability

I came across an incident that I couldn't believe, but don't know how to calculate the odds of it happening.  I witnessed someone roll 11 6's out of a total of 20 rolls.  As much as my college mathematics I remember, calculating the odds of this happening wasn't among them so if someone could provide me with both the calculation and answer.

Comment: Binomial distribution: http://www.mathnstuff.com/math/spoken/here/2class/90/binom2.htm

Comment: Perhaps you may want to test to see if the die is in fact biased?

Comment: Rare events nevertheless occur.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple.

The probability of getting a 6 (if your dice is fair) is $\frac{1}{6}$, and then  the probability of not getting a 6 is $\frac{5}{6}$. So the probability of 11 6's in a row, then 9 non-sixes would be $\frac{1}{6}^{11}\cdot\frac{5}{6}^9$. But it did not neccesarily happen in that order. So we need to take into account all possible permutations - orders of results, which would be $ {20 \choose 11} = \frac{20!}{11!(20-11)!}$

Put it together and you get

$prob = {20 \choose 11} \frac{1}{6}^{11}\cdot\frac{5}{6}^9$

This is also called a bernoulli process.

Comment: Thank you so much, I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is $${20 \choose 11}\left(\frac 16\right)^{11}\left(\frac 56\right)^9=\frac{41005859375}{457019805007872}\approx 9\cdot 10^{-5}$$

Answer (score 1):

you roll a dice, the probability to get $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$.

You roll it $n$ times, because the rolls are independent, the probability to get $m$ six $(m \leq n)$ is $${n \choose m} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^m \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-m}$$

Now, in your case, $n=20$ and $m=11$

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are all good -- particularly that of Daphne Keidar, which explains *why* the calculation works in the way it does. I'd like to add one more layer to this conversation.

I suspect it's not that you're interested in the fact that *exactly* 11 of the 20 dice landed on 6; rather, I assume you're interested in the fact that *at least* 11 of the 20 dice landed on 6. This is an important distinction, because when examining probabilities of events in iterated situations like these (such as dice, cards, or coins), the probability of any individual thing happening is quite small because there are so many things that might happen.

As an illustrative example, consider the situation of flipping 1000 coins. If I asked you  what the likeliest number of coins to be heads was, you would hopefully say 500, because you'd figure that about half of them should be heads. This intuition is right -- however, that event is still fairly unlikely, having a probability of just
$$\binom{1000}{500} 0.5^{500} \cdot 0.5^{500} \approx 0.025.$$
(Again, they *why* of that calculation is important, and is well-explained in Daphne's answer.) This can happen because there are so many possibilities for the number of coins to be heads; it could be $501, 499, 502, 498,$ and so on. Since many of these distinct possibilities have similar-ish likelihoods, their likelihoods must all be small.

What that means in your situation is that to honestly evaluate how likely this was to happen, you don't just need to compute the probability of *exactly* 11 dice out of 20 landing on 6; you should compute the probability of *at least* 11 dice out of 20 landing on 6. In other words, instead of
$$p(11) = \binom{20}{11} (1/6)^{11} \cdot (5/6)^{9} \approx 9 \cdot 10^{-5}$$
you really want
$$p(11) + p(12) + \dots + p(20). $$
This computation is straightforward but tedious, so we should ask a computer to do it for us. Using R:*

```
> pbinom(10, 20, 1/6, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.0001050194
```

So the *true* probability of your event is probably just a tick higher than otherwise advertised, sitting at around $\fbox{$1.1 \cdot 10^{-4}$}$. Note that the $p(11)$ term in the sum above is the overwhelmingly dominant term.

---

*The random variable in play here is called a [binomial random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which is why we use the function `pbinom` in R. The use of 10 instead of 11 in the first parameter is due to a weird implementation in the setting `lower.tail = FALSE`.